# Why are my UIScrollView's bounds changed when rotating the device?

Tags: uikit, xamarin.ios

I'm adding my view controller's view to the main window. My view controller's view is a UIScrollView.
The view's bounds are set to 500x500 and the view really is shown with the correct size.
However, if I rotate the device, the scroll view gets maximized and eats up all available scpace.

I do not have an auto resizing mask anywhere, nor do I change the scroll view's bounds.
What is changing the frame/bounds of my scroll view?

```
this.oPdfController = new PdfViewController(NSUrl.FromFilename("./pdffeatures.pdf"), 2); 
this.oPdfController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(40, 40), new SizeF(500, 500));
this.oPdfController.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None;
window.AddSubview (this.oPdfController.View);
```

Here's the source of the controller:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreAnimation;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PdfViewerTest
{
    public class PdfViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public PdfViewController (IntPtr handle) : base( handle )
        {
        }

        public PdfViewController (NSUrl oUrl, int iPage) : base(  )
        {
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void LoadView ()
        {
            base.LoadView ();

            UIScrollView oScrollView = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (new PointF (0, 0), new SizeF(1, 1)));
            oScrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate (this);
            oScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
            oScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
            oScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.ScrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor;
            this.View = oScrollView;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the scroll view.
        /// </summary>
        private UIScrollView ScrollView
        {
            get
            {
                return this.View as UIScrollView;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate for the scroll view.
        /// </summary>
        public class ScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
        {
            public ScrollViewDelegate (PdfViewController oParentController) : base(  )
            {
                this.oParentController = oParentController;
            }

            private PdfViewController oParentController;

            public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView (UIScrollView scrollView)
            {
                           // Not implemented here.
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this strange behaviour is due to `oScrollView` becoming a direct subview of the window.
I just tested your code and couldn't find a solution to keep the good size with this view structure, but a simple workaround is to add `oScrollView` as a subview of `PdfViewController.View` (just tested (on simulator), size stays the same even when rotating).

This way, your first code block should become :

```
this.oPdfController = new PdfViewController(NSUrl.FromFilename("pdffeatures.pdf"), 2);
window.AddSubview (this.oPdfController.View);
```

and your controller :

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreAnimation;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PdfViewerTest
{
    public class PdfViewController : UIViewController
    {

        UIScrollView oScrollView = null;

        public PdfViewController (IntPtr handle) : base( handle )
        {
        }

        public PdfViewController (NSUrl oUrl, int iPage) : base(  )
        {
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void LoadView ()
        {
            base.LoadView ();

            oScrollView = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (new PointF (0, 0), new SizeF(1, 1)));
            oScrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate (this);
            oScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
            oScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
            oScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.ScrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor;
            oScrollView.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(40, 40), new SizeF(500, 500));
            oScrollView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None;

            this.View.AddSubView(oScrollView);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the scroll view.
        /// </summary>
        private UIScrollView ScrollView
        {
            get
            {
                return oScrollView;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate for the scroll view.
        /// </summary>
        public class ScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
        {
            public ScrollViewDelegate (PdfViewController oParentController) : base(  )
            {
                this.oParentController = oParentController;
            }

            private PdfViewController oParentController;

            public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView (UIScrollView scrollView)
            {
                           // Not implemented here.
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something here? I thought in LoadView, one is supposed to ASSIGN a view to the controller's View property. Where would the view come from otherwise?

Comment: By default, any new `UIViewController` is initialized with a blank `UIView`. This behaviour may change if you override `LoadView()` without calling `base.LoadView()` inside, but I must confess I never tried. But you can try to comment your `LoadView()` method, and to override `ViewDidLoad()` with a simple `this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;`, it won't lead you to  a null ref exception, and fill your view with blue.

Comment: Seems to work but a quick test shows that it does not rotate. But that might be a hickup in my simulator. Thx!

Comment: Glad it helped! "might be a hickup in my simulator" >> I think so, because I tested adding a `UIWebView` inside `oScrollView` : `UIWebView web = new UIWebView(new RectangleF(20, 20, 460, 460)); web.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http://www.google.fr/"))); oScrollView.AddSubview(web);` and it rotates without any problem, even on simulator.